# JPA Repository use reserved word in column name for method name

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My entity property is called "dateAndTimeOfEstimation":

```
  @Column(nullable = true)
  private LocalDateTime dateAndTimeOfEstimation;
```

If I use it as part of a method name of a JPA repository, it does not work because the "And" is recognized as a query key word.
Example method name:
`findAllByDateAndTimeOfEstimation`. How can I make clear that the "And" should not be treated as query key word but as part of the column name?

Comment: Please share your entity too.

Comment: The entity is huge. Which parts are interesting for you?

Comment: The column/property names you refer in the method name

Comment: @Jens I added the column definition

Comment: This is a Spring method problem, not JPA. And it just won't work in spring if you are going to let Spring define the queries for you - change your property name or specify the query you want with the @Query annotation instead.

Comment: Call it "estimationdatetime"  and the problem goes away.

Comment: I don't have the option to change the property name. My question was if there is an option to "escape" the "And" in the method name

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to the `PropertyPath` class. It only takes property before. In your case it only takes date (to verify you can put a debug point) and then it is unable to find date as a property in the entity, thus it throws an error.

To avoid this error, there are two ways: -

1. You can change column name in SQL and in entity as variable.
2. You can write JPQL/Native query for the same `findAllByDateAndTimeOfEstimation()`.

Comment: I don't have the option to change the property name. My question was if there is an option to "escape" the "And" in the method name. If I write a deticated query, it does not properly handle NULL values which would be done with a query generated by method name.